# Space in string false when clearly should be true python

Tags: python, string

I am having immense problems with finding and removing whitespace and numbers from my file. The file I am reading looks like this:

```
01:001:001 In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.

01:001:002 And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was
           upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon
           the face of the waters.

01:001:003 And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.
```

and continues...

I have messed around with many functions like `.isspace()` and `.isdigit()` and  `" " in word`. You can see that in my code below.

```
def word_frequency(file_name):
    word_dict={}
    fileData = open(file_name, 'r')
    TotalData = str.lower(fileData.read())
    data = TotalData.split('\n')
    linecount=0
    wordcount=0
    fileData.close()
    for line in data:
        print("line",linecount,": ",line)
        linecount+=1
        #    C.A Break the line into words using spaces in between.
#    C.B Clean each word: strip leading and trailing whitespaces, 
# digits and punctuation characters and convert uppercase letters to lowercase.
        words = line.split(' ')
        for word in words:
            unregex=word
            word= word.strip(' .,:;') 
            word= word.strip(' ')
            if word.isdigit()==True:
                print(word,"removed")
                words.remove(unregex)
            print("word [",wordcount,"]: ",word)
            print(' ' in word)
            wordcount+=1
```

However, for whatever reason, my output keeps printing out the whitespaces and numbers. Here is a sample of what my output is:

```
Input file:  a.txt
line 0 :  01:001:001 in the beginning god created the heaven and the earth.
word [ 0 ]:  01:001:001
False
word [ 1 ]:  in
False
word [ 2 ]:  the
False
word [ 3 ]:  beginning
False
word [ 4 ]:  god
False
word [ 5 ]:  created
False
word [ 6 ]:  the
False
word [ 7 ]:  heaven
False
word [ 8 ]:  and
False
word [ 9 ]:  the
False
word [ 10 ]:  earth
```

...

```
line 3 :             upon the face of the deep. and the spirit of god moved upon
word [ 24 ]:  
False
word [ 25 ]:  
False
word [ 26 ]:  
False
word [ 27 ]:  
False
word [ 28 ]:  
False
word [ 29 ]:  
False
word [ 30 ]:  
False
word [ 31 ]:  
False
word [ 32 ]:  
False
word [ 33 ]:  
False
word [ 34 ]:  
False
word [ 35 ]:  upon
False
word [ 36 ]:  the
False
word [ 37 ]:  face
False
word [ 38 ]:  of
False
word [ 39 ]:  the
False
word [ 40 ]:  deep
False
word [ 41 ]:  and
False
word [ 42 ]:  the
False
word [ 43 ]:  spirit
False
word [ 44 ]:  of
False
word [ 45 ]:  god
False
word [ 46 ]:  moved
False
word [ 47 ]:  upon
```

Why are the whitespaces not regarded as whitespaces?

Comment: What exactly is the expected result of your program?

Comment: Ideally, I would like every word to be by itself. No verse number, period, whitespace, comma.

Comment: Have you looked into the `nltk` package?  It’s a text processing library with many of these features builtin.  Splitting, word/sentence parsing, etc. Or even regex ... ?

Comment: I have not but I can look into it.

Comment: They might be \t’s (tab escape characters) that are deceptively printed as whitespace but are not actually true whitespace